# Unbalance images dataset

Tags: classification, deep-learning, unbalanced-classes, overfitting, computer-vision

I want to create a deep learning model to classify images. My dataset has around 400 classes and the classes have different number of images..

- How can I train the deep learning network on unbalanced datasets of images?

I will use data augmentation to increase the amount of data. Also I will apply oversampling..

- When should I apply oversampling before or after splitting the images into training, testing, validation sets?
- Should I make oversampling manually?

Comment: what's the use of oversampling testing and validation anyways. I'd over sample training, but let test and validation be bit larger than they'd be with no oversampling..

Answer (score 1):

Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling will not solve a non-problem: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5004/1352) for a general motivation for this answer. See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)